# Is there a list of significant "foreshadowed" ideas/details between Harry Potter fanfiction and Harry Potter 5/6/7 books that were released later?

Tags: harry-potter, fan-fiction

Is/are there lists of instances of "borrowed" or "foreshadowed" ideas or details between Harry Potter fan-fiction and Harry Potter books 5, 6 or 7 that were released later?

This question as stated in the title is a bit too broad and might sound inflammatory, so let me clarify the details that didn't fit into already over-long title:

1. This is **not** meant in any way to imply anything negative about J. K. Rowling. I'm interested in significant ideas or details that are identical or very similar, but **not** in speculation as to the cause (e.g. "brilliant insight by fanfic author" vs "Rowling read and subconsciously remembered" vs "Rowling stole the idea"). Having actual documented confirmation as to what was the cause (e.g. Rowling's acknowledgement) would be a neat addendum, but not a requirement.
2. Just to spell it out, I'm looking for **significant** and **non-obvious** ideas, details or events that occured in fanfics released before the relevant 5th, 6th or 7th book was released (e.g. post-Goblet of Fire fanfics that were released before HP5).

   The idea/detail/event must be **significant**. E.g., the fact of an individual character dying is not really significant (including Dumbledore). Harry having to do the whole sacrificing himself thing is significant.

   It must be **non-obvious**. Who married whom at the end of book 7, or Dumbledore dying in general, or Neville ending up as a hero are pretty obvious from previous books or as possible plot twists. So is "a giant climactic battle at Hogwarts" - not predictable from previous books per se but way too obvious. Or "lots of characters dying in book 7".

   So if the list mostly consists of listing details like the examples above aren't what I'm looking for.
3. **I'm specifically interested in pre-compiled existing lists, NOT turning this into a list of one-per-answer examples. The list should contain at least 10 items which are significant and non-obvious.**
4. If you don't know of an existing list but know a lot of examples yourself, feel free to compile one off this site as a draft (e.g on Pastebin) and I would gladly verify if it contains enough valid entries; if so it would also constitute a valid acceptable answer.

NOTE: If the moderators feel that this last bullet is Bad Juju, 
i'll remove it from the question leaving only "Existing web lists only" #3.

Comment: Darn those / / / seriously hurt the readability of your question...

Comment: One thing that many people had predicted after book 5 was that there was a bit of Voldemort in Harry's soul.

Comment: *"I'm specifically interested in pre-compiled existing list, NOT turning this into a list of one-per-answer examples. The list should contain at least 10 items"* Err... why?

Comment: @Mgowen - to satisfy the moderators' immense level of hatred to any question that can possibly. theoretically, in a parallel universe, eventually turn into an "endless" list of answers. This was the ONLY way to not have the question closed by a moderator on the spot.

Comment: @DVK Well I guess they've left you with a choice between a closed question and an open one which will never get a single answer :( ... maybe just change it to something that might be answerable and see if you get anything? Then try and complain if they try to close it?

Comment: So, just to understand what you're asking for... you are asking for a pre-compiled list of fan fic that foreshadows ideas or specific plot points that occurred in books 5, 6, or 7, but you do not want a list of fics as a direct answer here on Stack Exchange? Just a link to an outside source?

Comment: @Slytherincess - to be more precise, I want either one, BUT the latter - if supplied via a tricle of many answers - will force the whole thing to become off-topic (at least in the earlier days, mods were extremely heavily against anything that even remotely smelled like a list question). Personally, I just want the information, form nonwithstanding.

Comment: Got it. Thank you. Will get back to you on this. :)

Comment: is it included that JKR read and loved an idea so much that she intentionally *incorporated it to honor it*?

Comment: @IvoFlipse - fixed... after four years!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[Fan Fics With Canon Foreshadowing](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1XFD9zAHBhaTL5bn4bTQt4vzfgyE-bjc5Ylz79Gw9kXY/edit?hl=en_US#)

I'll be honest -- this is a mixed list. Some of the foreshadowed events won't meet your criteria; some might. Also, you didn't specify any genre/pairings/ratings that you did NOT want to see, so I included everything I knew of or was recommended to me (I polled my f-list twice for fic recommendations). There are very well-written fics on the list, though (Textual Sphinx I like particularly.)

So, yeah. Giving this question the good old college try :)

---

**UPDATE**: So far, the best overall as far as foreshadowing seems to be Melindaleo's <s>"[The Seventh Horcrux](http://www.melindaleo.com/fics/tsh)".</s> [The Seventh Horcrux](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/2818538/1/The-Seventh-Horcrux).

The fic was finished 2006-11-11 (well before HP7 publishing on 2007-07-21), yet it included (frequently, with correct reasoning based on details in prior books):

- Obviously, Harry being the Seventh Horcrux
- The Horcrux being a result of killing Lily.
- Bill and Fleur's wedding
- Scrimgrour coming to the Burrow to question Harry about Dumbledore's death
- Death Eater attack at the end of that wedding
- R.A.B. being Regulus.
- Mundungus stole the locket Horcrux
- Percy Weasley turning back into the Good Guy
- Remus/Tonks being killed
- One of the Weasleys being killed (different one though) and one of the Weasley twins losing a body part.
- Dolores Umbridge being a big shot (though in the fic, she actually became the Minister of Magic).
- Voldemort taking control of the Ministry
- Harry meeting with Dumbledore in a combination of his mind and some sort of limbo.

Comment: I think I've read every HP-related trope imaginable by now. I rarely read fic anymore, though. I'm more into HP meta. :D

Comment: can I have a copy of that "good character study of Draco Malfoy" ?

Comment: Heh, this is actually the one fanfic I've ever read. I read it before the seventh book came out, and I actually prefer it to the real thing.

Comment: dead link on tsh :(

Comment: A lot of these seem rather obvious to me. Like, anyone who takes the time to go through a list of characters introduced by that point is going to realize Regulus is a main candidate. And Percy was never *bad*, just an antagonist. There's a big difference.