# Is there a resource compiling similarities of the *Harry Potter and the Cursed Child* to existing fanfics?

Tags: harry-potter, fan-fiction, the-cursed-child

Most people I talk to who are fanfic experts tend to point out that a vast majority of plot elements of *Harry Potter and the Cursed Child* can be found in fanfiction.

**Is there a resource that compiles such a reference?** (matching specific ideas/plot points to fanfics that used them earlier). Something like HP Lexicon.

Comment: I've seen many people comparing it to "[My Immortal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My_Immortal_(fan_fiction))" :-)

Comment: @Valorum - that's insulting to "My Immortal" :)

Comment: I think we are starting to, right here! http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/136035/in-what-ways-does-the-cursed-child-contradict-established-harry-potter-canon

Comment: @Skooba - Fanfiction troupes doesn't necessarily equal being non-canon-compliant. (E.g. time-travel is a common fan-fiction troup. The Wizarding World believing a rumor that someone went back several years with a time turner is non-canon-compliant.)

Comment: Given how many fanfictions there are,  perhaps the real question is which plot elements are *not* found in fanfiction.

Comment: Related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2655/is-there-a-list-of-significant-foreshadowed-ideas-details-between-harry-potter

Comment: If I write an answer and say [“There is now,”](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/19060/story-with-a-supercomputer-with-a-god-complex) is that acceptable?

Comment: @Adamant -  it is to me :)

Comment: @DVK-on-Ahch-To I am sorry to say this but the mere fact that a stupid thing such as My Immortal exists is an insult to itself and to the Potterverse..

Comment: @JaideepKhare - That is entirely correct.  But there is strong evidence that My Immortal is deliberately bad/trolling.  Cursed Child has no such excuse.

Comment: Could we make a community post and just add things that we find? Maybe we could compile our own here. For example, I randomly came across this [article](https://www.businessinsider.com.au/euphemia-rowle-in-harry-potter-and-the-cursed-child-was-in-fanfiction-2016-7) about a character that was created in a fanfic and shows up in the play. (Though sadly the fanfic has now been deleted).